# User Permissions Randomly Removed

Tags: permissions

have a user who lost permissions to author content in our site.  I went and checked the authoring group and realized she was no longer a member.  I figured someone had inadvertently removed her and simply added her back to the group.

Fast forward a month and this user lost her permissions again over the weekend.   I'm now pretty sure some process or job is removing her permissions and start to investigate fully. I discovered that this user has duplicate entries in the UserInfo table for the site in question. Both are marked as Active even though one has a value in the tp_Deleted field.

> From Microsoft: tp_Deleted - A value specifying whether the principal
>   is marked as deleted. If tp_Deleted is 0, the principal is not
>   deleted. If tp_Deleted is not 0, the principal is marked as deleted,
>   and the value is the user identifier that was associated with this
>   principal. The deleted state can be used for user information, rather
>   than dropping entries from the table, to preserve list item ownership
>   information. A user or domain group with the tp_Deleted value set to
>   nonzero can be restored by setting the tp_Deleted value to 0 and
>   updating other fields as necessary.

Does anyone know whether having an entry in the UserInfo table with a value other than 0 in the tp_Deleted field with a tp_IsActive status value of 1 is valid?

What timer job(s) are responsible for removing users from Groups?